# Replacing text in vector with numbers?

Tags: r, vector, replace

guys. I searched, but failed. I totally new to this stuff.
I have a dataset - **art**.
I am going **art$paper** to see that I have two types of paper - watercolor and drawing.
I need to create distributions for both types of paper. 
I tried **a <- art[art$paper=="watercolor", ]**, then **hist(a)**, but it writes
**Error in hist.default(a) : 'x' must be numeric**
I understand that types of papers should be numeric. How can I replace it. I am bad in R, so my questions are stupid.
I need to create a distribution of watercolor and drawing paper separately.
Many thanks.

Comment: If you need to replace the text use `hist(as.integer(factor(a$paper)))` or with `match` i.e. `hist(match(a$paper, unique(a$paper)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are two variables inside `art$paper` it is propably a factor. Histogram works only for numeric variables.

You can try this:

```
barplot(prop.table(table(art$paper)))
```

Or use *ggplot2*:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot <- ggplot(art,aes(x=paper))
ggplot + geom_histogram(fill="black") # numbers
ggplot + geom_histogram(fill="red",aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) # histogram
```